# 20.04 - Is it possible to create an exact copy of my OS in order to test things on it?

Tags: 20.04, docker

I am new to Linux and I have a VPS on which I am hosting things such as some websites, api's and databases. What I want to do is somehow create an exact copy of my OS so that I can test installing things and making changes and see if the result is what I expect. And if it is not then I simply delete the copy and revert back to the revert back to the "Original" instance.

The Idea I have in my hand is to create a "box" in the operating system. This "box" is configured exactly the same way my "main" OS is. Because they are exactly the same, I can make changes to the "box" and in doing so I would know exactly what would happen to the "main" OS. This way it would just be a simple matter of deleting the "box" if I mess anything up.
I apologise for not knowing what tags to use.

**Edit**

What about docker? Could I possibly have everything setup on my OS, and have a container interact with the OS? That way if I mess anything up in the container then I just delete it?

Comment: The usual test environment "box" is a Virtual Machine (VM). A typical VM is not an *exact* copy: The firmware is different, and a test environment may have sanitized or sample data instead of real data. Several good VM applications are in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @user535733, What about docker? Could I possibly have everything setup on my OS, and have a container interact with the OS? That way if I mess anything up in the container then I just delete it?

Comment: You could definitely use an LXD container for it. I'm not familiar enough with Docker to say.

Comment: Sounds like something BTRFS snapshots would be ideal for. I imagine the copying and deletion is instant as well, considering it's copy-on-write.